# How can I set up the database in `g` before the session interface is opened during a request?

Tags: python, flask

I'm trying to set up a database connection and store it in `flask.g` to access later in the [session interface](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/api/#session-interface).  I found that Flask processes the request in the following order:

1. `Flask.wsgi_app` sets `RequestContext`
2. Then it calls`full_dispatch_request`
3. `full_dispatch_request` calls `preprocess_request`
4. Finally, `preprocess_request` calls functions from `before_request_funcs`

As far as I understand, functions stored in `before_request_funcs` are the first place where I can actually access `flask.g`.  But `session_interface.open_session` is already called in `RequestContext.push` method, long before my ability to set anything on `flask.g`.

A comment in `RequestContext.push` seems to indicate that I should have been able to set up the database before that point.

```
# Open the session at the moment that the request context is
# available. This allows a custom open_session method to use the
# request context (e.g. code that access database information
# stored on `g` instead of the appcontext).
```

Am I missing something?  How can I set up the database connection in `g` before the session is opened?